# Decoding HTML entity in php doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, html, html-entities

```
$string = "C-Tru Process Equipments P&#146;ship";
echo html_entity_decode($string);
```

I expect to get: `C-Tru Process Equipments P’ship` result but the output is `C-Tru Process Equipments P&#146;ship`

I put my string into https://mothereff.in/html-entities and this shows me the result perfectly, my file with the string is UTF8 formatted.

Comment: I just ran this on my local test machine with PHP7.2, and I get the apostrophe as expected. I'm thinking this is perhaps to do with the browser you are using? I'm using the latest Chrome 68.0.3440.106

Comment: i tryt it in the terminal(putty), i save the result in a UTF8 Mysql DB which also shows me my result. Currently i helped me with preg_replace("/&#[0-9]{1,};/", " ", $val) but not a perfect solution